# Is this signal band-limited?

Tags: signal-processing

I'm self-learning signal processing now, and I've run into this question about band-limited signals:

Consider the signal $x(t) = 1$ for $0 \leq t \leq T$ and $0$ otherwise.
I've found that its Fourier transform is:
$$ x_\phi(\Omega) = \frac{1-e^{-j\Omega T}}{j\Omega} $$

How can I determine if this signal is band-limited signal, or not?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if there is some $R>0$ such that $x_\phi (\Omega)=0$ holds for all $|\Omega |\geq R$. That would be the definition.

Another way is the following: Every unlimited signal is smooth (infinitely differentiable), even analytic by the Palye Wiener Theorem. Is this the case for your signal? (Is your signal continuous?)

Comment: I don't think, intuitivelly, that my signal holds the definition. But how can I prove this?

Comment: Try to find a sequence $(\Omega_n)_n$ with $\Omega_n \to \infty$ and $x_\phi (\Omega_n)\neq 0$ for all $n$. This will.imply that the definition is not satisfied.

Comment: What about $f(x) = 1$ if $x = 0$ and $f(x) = 0$ is $x\neq 0$? It's not smooth but has unlimited bandwidth.

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85: First of all, you probably mean that the function has **limited** bandwidth. The (apparent) contradiction is resolved by noting that the actual statement is that there is a smooth function $g$ with $f=g$ **almost everywhere** (i.e. on the complement of a null set). I will edit the post this evening to reflect this.

Comment: @PhoemueX Perhaps I am misinterpreting "unlimited signal" to mean a bandlimited signal?